# Reference library certificates from Android Network Security Configuration?

Tags: android, android-network-security-config

Starting from Android API level 24 it is possible to define a Network Security Configuration and reference it from the Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
   <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                   ... >
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#manifest (accessed 2021-08-10)

I have a use case where a number of CA certificates are included in an Android library that I am using. I would like to restrict my security configuration to these certificates using trust-anchors.

The network security configuration allows this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#ConfigCustom (accessed 2021-08-10)

But the certificates are located in my Android library and I don't want to duplicate the files.
How can I reference the library CA certificates from my apps network security configuration?

Comment: `@raw/my_ca` would work for a `my_ca` raw resource located in a library or in an app, unless steps are taken in the library to prevent this.

Comment: OK, so a library resource works but not a library asset?

Comment: I do not know of a network security configuration syntax that works for assets, whether those assets are in a library or in the main app module.

Comment: OK, I have moved the certificates in the library from assets to resources and it looks promising ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CA certificates should be put in the `res/raw` folder, **not** in the `assets` folder, in the library project.
This way it is possible to reference the certificates from the app using the library through the network security configuration.

At least everything compiles now. Although, I have not yet verified a fully working setup due to a different issue, see: [Combine Network Security Configuration with OkHttp and custom CAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738700/combine-network-security-configuration-with-okhttp-and-custom-cas)